# Locked myself out of SSH with UFW

Tags: ssh, iptables, ubuntu-12.04, ufw

I had my  server set up to accept SSH connections on port 21966, I followed some steps to configure ufw however it has now locked me out of all SSH access on any port!

I've been able to boot my server into 'rescue' mode, providing me with an SSH rescue account, through which I am able to mount the hard drives and see my files. I do not know what to do from here, as the ufww service isn't running so I cannot disable it or uninstall.

Comment: Have you write access to config files?
If so, [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=823741&p=5329142#post5329142) might be helpful.

Comment: yes, but I don't know what to write!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your ufw rules should be located in `/lib/ufw/user.rules` config file.
Modify that file so that somewhere between `### RULES ###` and `### END RULES ###` section there are the following entries:

```
### tuple ### allow any 21966 0.0.0.0/0 any 0.0.0.0/0 in
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp --dport 21966 -j ACCEPT
```

Additionally make sure that your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file has `Port 21966` entry(instead of port 22).

Comment: Thank you, how does one adjust it to allow an SSH connection on port 21966?

Comment: @James see my updated answer.